# Reiniciar servidor NodeJS con cada cambio en el index?

Tags: nodejs, parse.com

He montado un Parse Server en un ubuntu, y cada vez que añado una modificación al index.js tengo que reiniciar, lo cual tarda 4 o 5 segundos en volver a la vida.

Hay alguna forma más optima de añadir cambios sin que se caiga el server?

Comment: Con qué propósito reinicias el servidor?

Comment: Pues si añado algún cambio de configuración de alguna clave de acceso , no funciona hasta que hago el reboot

Comment: Para escuchar a eventos que se disparen cuando se producen cambios en un archivo puedes usar esto https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener , pero quizás si explicas un poco más en profundidad qué es lo que no funciona antes de reiniciar el servidor, quizás podamos ayudarte para que no tengas que hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## La respuesta es sí y no

Para el ejemplo que preguntaste (la conexión a la base) hay una solución. En vez de tener tu index.js así:

```
var dbMotor = require('my-sql'); // o require('pg-promise-strict'); 
var config = require('./config.json');
var dbOpen = dbMotor.connect(config.parametrosDb);

var app = require('express')();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
   dbOpen.query("SELECT ALL ... ", function(err, data){
      res.end(data);
   });
});
```

se puede tener un reiniciador de base de datos que solo reinicia esa parte:

```
var dbMotor = require('my-sql'); // o require('pg-promise-strict'); 
var config;
var dbOpen;

var app = require('express')();

function start(){
  config = require('./config.json');
  dbOpen = dbMotor.connect(config.parametrosDb);
}

start(); // lee todo al inciar el servidor

app.get('/reset', function(req, res){
  start(); // vuelve a leer todo al resetear
  res.end("reset ok at "+new Date());
});

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
  dbOpen.query("SELECT ALL ... ", function(err, data){
    res.end(data);
  });
});
```

### Análisis de la respuesta

1. Es una simplificación (faltan muchas cosas, el listen, cerrar la base de datos si se va a volver a abrir, etc)
2. La ventaja es que no hay que cortar la ejecución del `node index.js`
3. Lo importante a observar es que sí o sí hay que volver a ejecutar `start` hay que ver cuánto de los 4 ó 5 segundo se lo llevan tareas que hay que volver a hacer
4. En esta simplificación hay que llamar a `/reset` desde el navegador, se pueden elegir otros activadores, por ejemplo un `watchFile` que esté observando si hubo modificaciones en el archivo de configuración.
5. Otra alternativa es tener un `start` para cada tipo de cosa, uno para la base de datos, otro para leer templates de disco, otro para cambiar de puerto, etc.

### Conclusión

**No hay una solución mágica**, todo hay que probarlo y programarlo, **alguien paga el costo**, el programador programando, el programador esperando que arranque en cada reinicio, el usuario con la baja de performance (de algo que está todo el tiempo viendo si cambió), el usuario con la probabilidad de que algo tenga error.

Comment: Node ya trae algo más optimizado para observar cambios en archivos que un setInterval https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener o https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener

Comment: Gracias por lo de watch y watchFile. No lo había visto y es muy útil.

Answer (score 2):

instala forever

```
sudo npm install forever --global
```

y luego inicias tu app (en modo debug) con:

```
forever -f -w index.js
```

luego si haces algun cambio en tu index.js tendras una salida como esta

```
error: restarting script because change changed
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

el flag -w indica a node que este atento a algun cambio en el archivo index.js y que se reinicie, lo interpreta como un error pero no lo es.

Comment: Existe algo parecido para hacer que vuelva a llamar al start al modificar X archivo? Supongo que lo de watch y watchFile sirve, pero sin ir a tan bajo nivel?